# Calculating length of OS Terrain50 contours for filtering prior to laser cutting - getting NaN $length

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to generate an SVG per height based on the contour data from https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/Terrain50 (for laser cutting). It's an island group where I want to build up a physical height map using layers of board.

I've actually managed to create the file (merge four vectors to one, split on PROP_VALUE - gives me a .shp per height - then export to SVG). So - I now have an SVG with the 6 layers 2.09 (meanWaterHigh), 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50.

But - there is one more thing I would like to do - I would also like to remove any tiny features. With the output scaled down to about 30cm a side - some of the features are under a millimeter in size - hard to cut - no point in trying to mount/glue - and just distracting.

Googling this has led me to look at trying to calculate each items length then using that to filter the short ones away.

But - $length in attribute table > field calculator for each item gives me NaN.

I have found out that each is a geometry: MultiLineString.

I suspect that I am missing something fairly obvious here - but am not sure what search terms will lead me in the correct direction ?